# How can I log out some details when Spring MVC3 sends an HTTP error response such as 400?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

I'd like to see some details in my logs of why a request resulted in a HTTP error code, such as a 400 invalid request.

Is it possible to get Spring MVC3 to log some info out when it responds to a request with an error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses Log4J behind the scenes, and adds a LOT of information at the `DEBUG` level.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

Add a logger to your Log4J configuration and see if what you are after is in there.